# Can't see roles and privileges from groovy script after creating in Nexus

Tags: java, groovy, orientdb, nexus

I execute this groovy script inside the Nexus

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.common.entity.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.authz.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.role.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.privilege.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.user.UserManager;
import org.sonatype.nexus.selector.*
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap

// use container.lookup to fetch internal APIs we need to use
def selectorManager = container.lookup(SelectorManager.class.name)
def securitySystem = container.lookup(SecuritySystem.class.name)
def authorizationManager = security.getSecuritySystem().getAuthorizationManager(UserManager.DEFAULT_SOURCE)

def userMail = "user@mail.com"
def requiredFormats = ["maven2", "docker"]
// ----------------
def username = userMail.toLowerCase().substring(0, userMail.indexOf("@"));
def pathMap = ["docker": "^\"/v2/${username}/\"", "maven2": "^\"${username}/\"", "npm": "^\"@${username}\"", "raw": "^\"${username}\""]
// ----------------
def privilegeIds = []

requiredFormats.each{ requiredFormat ->

  // create content selector (if not already present)
  def selectorConfig = new SelectorConfiguration(
      "name" : username + "-" + requiredFormat + "-selector",
      "type" : "csel",
      "description" : "Selector for " + username + " to see part of the " + requiredFormat + " repository",
      "attributes" : ["expression": "format==\"" + requiredFormat + "\" and path=" + pathMap.get(requiredFormat).toString()]
  )

  if (selectorManager.browse().find { it -> it.name == selectorConfig.name } == null) {
    selectorManager.create(selectorConfig)
  }

  // create content selector privilege
  def privelegeProperties = ImmutableMap.builder()
    .put("contentSelector", selectorConfig.getName())
    .put("repository", "*-" + requiredFormat)
    .put("actions", '*')
    .build()
  def privilegeConfig = new org.sonatype.nexus.security.privilege.Privilege(
      "id": "id-" + username + "-" + requiredFormat + "-privelege",
      "name": username + "-" + requiredFormat + "-privilege",
      "description": "Privelege for " + username + " to access the " + requiredFormat + " repository",
      "type": "repository-content-selector",
      "properties": privelegeProperties
  )
  privilegeIds.add(privilegeConfig.getId())
  try {
    authorizationManager.getPrivilege(privilegeConfig.getId())
  } catch (NoSuchPrivilegeException ex) {
    authorizationManager.addPrivilege(privilegeConfig)
  }
}

// create a role with privileges
def roleConfig = new org.sonatype.nexus.security.role.Role(
    "roleId": username + "-role",
    "source": "Nexus",
    "name": username + "-role",
    "description": "Role for " + username + " to access the repositories",
    "readOnly": false,
    "privileges": privilegeIds,
    "roles": []
)
try {
  privilegeIds.each{ privilegeId ->
    authorizationManager.getRole(username + "-role").addPrivilege(privilegeId)
  }
  // def rolePriveleges = authorizationManager.getRole(username + "-role").privileges.add(privilegeIds)
  // authorizationManager.deleteRole(username + "-role")
  // roleConfig.setPrivileges(rolePriveleges)
} catch (NoSuchRoleException) {
  // create a roleIdentifier for role
  def roleIdentifier = new org.sonatype.nexus.security.role.RoleIdentifier('default', roleConfig.getRoleId())
  authorizationManager.addRole(roleConfig)

  // assign a role to a user
  def user = security.getSecuritySystem().getUser(userMail)

  user.addRole(roleIdentifier)
  // security.getSecuritySystem().setUsersRoles(user.userId, 'LDAP', user.getRoles())
}
```

Then I can see the role with privileges via web but when I execute the following script I get an error NoSuchRoleException.

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.user.UserManager
import org.sonatype.nexus.common.entity.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.role.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.authz.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.selector.*
def securitySystem = container.lookup(SecuritySystem.class.name)
security.getSecuritySystem().getAuthorizationManager(UserManager.DEFAULT_SOURCE).deleteRole('<the correct ID of the created role>')
```

I studied the Nexus code and existing custom solutions from forums as much as I could, but I don't understand, what's the problem.

Please don't refer me to this [link](https://gist.github.com/nblair/1a0e05713c3edb7e5360c2b0222c7623)

So, I want to can:

1. Create ContentSelector (✔)
2. Create Privileges using ContentSelectors (✔)
3. Create Role which aggregate privileges (✔)
4. Assign role to LDAP user (✔)
5. Delete any Privilege from existing Role (x)
6. Add any Privilege from existing Role (x)
7. Cancel Role for user (x)
8. Delete Role (✔)

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you'll likely be interested to know that the next release (3.19.0 will have a slew of new REST endpoints  that will address blob store config, licensing, security (users, roles, privileges), LDAP, email config, etc.   So using groovy scripting for this use case won't be needed.  If you can wait a few weeks for that release you'll find your provisioning task a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for answering. the problem was solved, the error was made by me in groovy script due to inattention. When can I expect an update?

Comment: @Nikolai 3.19 is out now.  Suggestion to either remove this post or post an answer as it does not seem helpful as is.